# Power BI -- ignore table selection for a line and clustered column chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

when I select a specific unit in the table (Visual 3) below, I want only a partial dynamic change in the line and clustered column chart (Visual 2). Specifically, I want the bars to indicate the rent change over time, but I want the line to remain unchanged (the line in Visual 4 is what I am looking for). I'm unsure how to disregard the unit selection just for the measure used in 'rent change in city'. ***In my final dashboard, visual 4 would be discarded.***

[image]

***I have tried All, Allexcept, Removefilters, but none of these work.***

**This is the measure I created for the bar columns:**

```
Rent change in = 
var one_year_filter = FILTER('TABLE', DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) >=0 && DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) <= 12)                                                                                                    
var two_year_filter = FILTER('TABLE', DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) >=0 && DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) <= 24) 

return
IF(ISBLANK(SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Expiring Month'[Value]),

"Last 12 Months",CALCULATE(SUM('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), one_year_filter),         
"Last 24 Months",CALCULATE(SUM('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), two_year_filter),

CALCULATE(SUM('TABLE'[Rent Change in]))
)), blank(), SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Expiring Month'[Value]),


"Last 12 Months",CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Rent Change in]), one_year_filter),        
"Last 24 Months",CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Rent Change in]), two_year_filter),
CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Rent Change in]))
))
```

**This is the measure I created for the line:**

```
Rent Change in by City = 

var one_year_filter = FILTER('TABLE', DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) >=0 && DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) <= 12)                                                                                                    
var two_year_filter = FILTER('TABLE', DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) >=0 && DATEDIFF('TABLE'[Contr.strt],TODAY(),MONTH) <= 24) 

return
IF(ISBLANK(SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Expiring Month'[Value]),

"Last 12 Months",CALCULATE(AVERAGE('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), ALLEXCEPT(DIM,DIM[City]), REMOVEFILTERS('TABLE'[Unit]), one_year_filter),         
"Last 24 Months",CALCULATE(AVERAGE('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), ALLEXCEPT(DIM,DIM[City]), REMOVEFILTERS('TABLE'[Unit]), two_year_filter),


CALCULATE(AVERAGE('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), ALLEXCEPT(DIM,DIM[City]),REMOVEFILTERS('TABLE'[Unit]))
)), blank(), SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Expiring Month'[Value]),


"Last 12 Months",CALCULATE(AVERAGE('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), ALLEXCEPT(DIM,DIM[City]), REMOVEFILTERS('TABLE'[Unit]), one_year_filter),         
"Last 24 Months",CALCULATE(AVERAGE('TABLE'[Rent Change in]), ALLEXCEPT(DIM,DIM[City]), REMOVEFILTERS('TABLE'[Unit]), two_year_filter),   

CALCULATE(AVERAGE('TABLE'[Change in]), ALLEXCEPT(DIM,DIM[City]),REMOVEFILTERS('TABLE'[Unit]))
)
)
```

Comment: Add ALL('<unitcolumntable>'[Unit]) to your calculates in the Line measure

Comment: Hi mxix, I tried it before, but it doesn't work

Comment: you could edit the interactions in the format pane so that when a user clicks on anything in visual  3, turn off interactoins in visual 4

Comment: Hi zach, in my final dashboard, visual 4 would be discarded. (I have revised my post above), sorry for the confusion